# Jump to thymeleaf-iterated section on other webpage

Tags: html, hyperlink, thymeleaf

I try to jump to a section on another page that is an entry in a `th:each` loop.

I have a list of student names on one page, and clicking it will bring you to a page with more information of every user:

```html
<div th:each="student : ${getAllStudents()}">
    <a th:href="@{linkToOtherPage}">[[${student.name}]]</a>
</div>
```

And on the other page with extra information for every user I have:

```html
<div th:each="student : ${getAllStudents()}">
    <div id="studentInformation">
        <h1>[[${student.name}]]</h1>
        <h3>[[${student.age}]]</h3>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

So say that on position one in the list there is someone called Robert, and on position 20 someone called Sandy. **What do I need to do in order to jump to Sandy when clicking Sandy's name**?

I tried adding `#studentInformation` to the page with student names, so:

```html
<div th:each="student : ${getAllStudents()}">
    <a th:href="@{linkToOtherPage}#studentInformation">[[${student.name}]]</a>
</div>
```

But that brings me to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to link to a section using an `#expression`, that expression must be unique. If you use `#studentInformation` for each section, it doesn't know where to link to.

If the lists are always going to be in the same order, something like this will work for you:

First page:

```
<div th:each="student, status: ${getAllStudents()}">
    <a th:href="|@{linkToOtherPage}#student${status.index}|">[[${student.name}]]</a>
</div>
```

Second page:

```
<div th:each="student, status: ${getAllStudents()}">
    <div th:id="|student${status.index}|">
        <h1>[[${student.name}]]</h1>
        <h3>[[${student.age}]]</h3>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

(By appending the index in the array to each id, you can link to an individual student.)

Comment: Quick question: Can you jump to a `<div>` like this? I thought you needed a `<section>` or an anchor - something like `<a name="top"></a>`. (I have not tried jumping to a div.)

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you! There was one small issue though, and that was that the list on different pages are unfortunately not in the same order (on one page it is sorted alphabetically). However, I solved that by using `status.current`, instead of `status.index`.

Comment: @andrewjames You are already jumping to a `<div>` right? By adding `#...` to a link you can jump to an `id`. On the second page the `id` is added to a `<div>`, so essentially you are jumping to the `<div>`

Comment: I see - thank you @user14571536. I thought `#` could only be used to jump to a limited set of tags - not to any ID, regardless of the tag. I learn something every day.